# CCSequesnce in Cocos 2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

Why Null is passed in CCSequence action?

logo->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCDelayTime::create(1.4),CCEaseBounceOut::create(CCMoveTo::create(1.4, ccd(254,787))),CCRepeat::create(CCSequence::create(CCRotateTo::create(1.3, -3),CCRotateTo::create(1.3, 6),NULL), 100),NULL));

Answer (score 1):

Null is passed just to tell where the list ends. used to terminate the sequence.
if you don't pass null at end of sequence your app may crash on device.

Comment: if i pass null at end of ccsequence, app is not crashed in device.

Comment: but why , in device not crashed, in simulator it crashes?