# Crash on CCAnimation

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

When i run the below animation code it crash on simulator. but working fine on Device.

Code:-

```
CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("pic2.png");
    pSprite->setPosition( ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2) );
    this->addChild(pSprite, 0);



    //Animation
    CCAnimation *animate = CCAnimation::create();
    for (int i = 2; i <=7; i++)
    {
        char frameName[128] = {0};
        sprintf(frameName, "pic%d.png", i);
        animate->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(frameName) ;
    }

    animate->setDelayPerUnit(0.1f); // This animation contains 3 frames, will continuous 2.8 seconds.
    animate->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true); // Return to the 1st frame after the 3rd frame is played.

    CCAnimate *animaction = CCAnimate::create(animate);
    pSprite->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCRepeat::create(animaction, 1),
                                          CCDelayTime::create(2.0f),
                                          CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback))));
```

Exactly on ccsequence its crashing. i got this "reference count should greater than 0" with Exc_Bad_acess[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line -

```
pSprite->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCRepeat::create(animaction, 1),
                                          CCDelayTime::create(2.0f),
                                          CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback))));
```

with

```
pSprite->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCRepeat::create(animaction, 1),
                                          CCDelayTime::create(2.0f),
                                          CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback)),NULL));
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114080/ccsequesnce-in-cocos-2dx/24114302#24114302)

Comment: but why , in device not crashed, in simulator it crashes?

Comment: i don't know the reason mate, but i was having same issue in one of my project and this worked out for me.